# C# Asynchronous File Copy with Progress Bar

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I'm trying to write a C# application that updates a progress bar as multiple files have been copied through. I am using this method to do the copying which takes a `Dictionary<string, string>`:

```
public static async Task CopyFiles(Dictionary<string, string> files, IProgress<int> progressCallback)
{
    for (var x = 0; x < files.Count; x++)
    {
        var item = files.ElementAt(x);
        var from = item.Key;
        var to = item.Value;

        using (var outStream = new FileStream(to, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.Read))
        {
            using (var inStream = new FileStream(from, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))
            {
                await inStream.CopyToAsync(outStream);
            }
        }

        var percentComplete = ((x + 1) / files.Count) * 100;
        //progressCallback((int)((x + 1) / files.Count) * 100);
        progressCallback.Report(percentComplete);
    }
}
```

Inside my main class I am using the following code to try to update my progress bar (progressBar1) but this code doesn't appear to be working, it seems to complete the ProgressBar towards the END of the copying of both files and it takes like a second to complete, not sure why this is happening.

```
private async void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
        button4.Enabled = false;

        var progress = new Progress<int>(percent =>
        {
            progressBar1.Value = percent;
        });

        await Copier.CopyFiles(new Dictionary<string, string> {
            { Source1, Destination1 },
            { Source2, Destination2 }
        },
            progress);

        button4.Enabled = true;
        MessageBox.Show("Completed");
    }
}
```

Comment: Consider to asynchronously invoke `progressCallback` using dispatcher (to run callback in UI thread). As for doesn't work, what is expected behavior? Should take longer than one second? If you replace `CopyToAsync` with `Task.Delay`, is the problem still?

Comment: use var percentComplete = (((x + 1) * 100) / 2)  ****** when use ((x + 1) / files.Count) * 100 result is zero .

Comment: @Sinatr that's what the Progress bar already does. There's nothing wrong with it.  It's actually preferable to hard-coding calls to the UI or worse, specific controls. That integer division on the other hand, can be interesting

Comment: The integer division guarantees the value will be 0 for anything less that `files.Count`, at which point the result will be 1. There's no reason to calculate a percentage in the async method though. You can specify the current and maximum value of the progress bar, and report just `x`. You can report complex objects, not just primitive types

Answer (score 1):

The problem is caused because the integer division `x + 1 / files.Count` returns zero for every `x` except the last. You can fix this by multiplying by 100 first (`100*(x+1)/files.Count`) but there are better alternatives.

There's no need to calculate and report a percentage in `CopyFiles`. You can set the progress bar's Maximum value :

```
    private async void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    {
            button4.Enabled = false;

            var files = new Dictionary<string, string> {
                { Source1, Destination1 },
                { Source2, Destination2 }
            };
            
            progressBar1.Maximum=files.Count;
            progressBar1.Value =0;
            var progress = new Progress<int>(x =>
            {
                progressBar1.Value = x+1;
            });

            await Copier.CopyFiles(files,progress);

            button4.Enabled = true;
            MessageBox.Show("Completed");
        }
    }
```

And report just the current iteration :

```
    public static async Task CopyFiles(Dictionary<string, string> files, IProgress<int> progressCallback)
    {
        for (var x = 0; x < files.Count; x++)
        {
            
            ...
            progressCallback.Report(x);
        }
    }
```

`IProgress< T>` can handle complex objects, not just primitive types. It's possible to report both the iteration and the file names for display in the status bar :

```
record CopyProgress(int Iteration, string From, string To);
...

var progress = new Progress<int>(x =>
        {
            progressBar1.Value = x.Iteration;
            statusText.Text = $"Copied {x.From} to {x.To}";
        });

...
progressCallback.Report(new CopyProgress(x,from,to);
```

Comment: dict.Count -- means files.Count? Right?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, unfortunately the solution doesn't seem to work it's still doing the same thing. the button disables, it starts copying in the background, then just a second before it's completed the progressbar quickly completes then it displays the messageBox with "Completed"